# meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3: Change {{ > loginbuttons }} to icon

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using `meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` in my meteor app to let the users register and login. This as working well.
But now I want to change, what is displayed by `{{ > loginButtons }}`. Right now I see 'Login / Register'. But I want to replace this by the font awesome icon `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>`. Just an icon, no text.

But I can't find the right place to make this changes.

I tried to do:

```
accountsUIBootstrap3.map('en', {
    loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown: {
        signIn: '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>',
        up: "Register"
    }
})
```

But this HTML won't be rendered. Also I can't remove the `/` which still will be shown in front of 'Register'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` is hardcoded [here](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/login_buttons_dropdown.html#L44). You might be able to achieve what you want by replacing the `_loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown` template with a modified version, by doing something like this:

Some html file:

```
<template name="my_loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown">
  <li id="login-dropdown-list" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        {{> _loginButtonsLoggedOutAllServices}}
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Some client-side js code:

```
Template._loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown = Template.my_loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown;
```